# Expresion regular señala toda la cadena

Tags: javascript, regex

La siguiente expresión regular debe encontrar todas las coincidencias de `${cualquier expresion}` el código es el siguiente:

```js
const reg= /\$\{[^]+\}/g
let txt= '`${i + " test"} RESULT ${2 + 4} now ${i} hi`'
let resultado= [...txt.matchAll(reg)];
console.log(resultado)
```

Como notaran, el resultado es que extrae casi toda la cadena, el funcionamiento correcto deberia imprimir en consola un array de 3 elementos que contendría los `${cualquier expression}`

#### update

El siguiente caso muestra un error que se genera si uso: `[^}]`

```js
const reg= /\$\{[^}]+\}/g
let i= "some"
let txt= `${i + " test"} RESULT ${2 + 4} now ${i + "}" } hi`
let txtString= '`${i + " test"} RESULT ${2 + 4} now ${i + "}" } hi`'
let resultado= [...txtString.matchAll(reg)];
console.log(resultado)
console.log(txt)
```

la expresión `${i + "}" }` es valida en JavaScript por lo tanto la expresión regular debe devolver `[${i + "}" },demás coincidencias]` pero en el ejemplo mostrado devuelve

```
${i + "}
```

Comment: ¿Cual sería el resultado para esta expresión ``'`${i + "`${i}`"}`'``? Tambíen es válida en Javascript

Comment: Me encantaía ayudar, pero no entiendo nada, pero nada, de la pregunta. Lo lamento.

Comment: @Marcos seria `[${i + "\`${i}\`"}, demás coincidencias]`

Comment: @Usiel y ¿que tal esta expresión ``'`${i + `${i}`}`'``? Estas necesitando algo más complejo que simples RegEx. Te recomiendo leer [este articulo](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/09/29/bracket-pair-colorization).

Comment: @Marcos en el ultimo caso devolvería `${i + \`${i}\`}` solo buscara los `${}` sobre la linea no los anidados

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer coincidir a las llaves más internas con:

```
/\$\{[^{}]*\}/g
```

Además, si quisieras ignorar todo lo que está entre comillas, se puede con la siguiente estructura:

```
/\$\{[^"{}]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"{}]*)*\}/g
```

Sin embargo, en JavaScript es imposible hacer que `RegExp` coincida con llaves anidadas. No existe recursividad ni grupos balanceados en expresiones regulares (sí en otros lenguajes como PHP, Perl y .Net).

Answer (score 0):

En la primera expresión que pones nada evita que la expresión tome también otras llaves como parte de la búsqueda. La actualización que pones es casi correcta, evitando la llave de cierre, sólo te falta escaparla. Con esa corrección, el código

```
const reg= /\$\{[^\}]+\}/g;
let i= "some";
let txt= `${i + " test"} RESULT ${2 + 4} now ${i + "}" } hi`;
let txtString= '`${i + " test"} RESULT ${2 + 4} now ${i + "}" } hi`';
let resultado= [...txtString.matchAll(reg)];
console.log(resultado);
console.log(txt);
```

devuelve la matriz [ [ "${i + " test"}" ], [ "${2 + 4}" ], [ "${i + "}" ] ]